# Add extra glyphicon to bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons

I'm using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), and icons were supplied with ([glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/)).

I need the icon "glyphicons-group", which apparently is not supplied by default with bootstrap.

Do you know how I could add this extra icon to bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i will use [Fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/), free and great